# Thermal properties of salt water

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

Is there a big difference between salt water and normal tap water in terms of thermal properties (heat capacity, for example)?

If so, can anyone give me a table of thermal and thermodynamic properties of salt water?

Comment: Not quite what you asked for but a major point to note is that freezing point can be lowered substantially using salt. A saturated salt solution may not freeze in a typical domestic freezer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIT provide a table of water properties at a range of salinity and temperature values: http://web.mit.edu/seawater/

There is also excel/matlab correlations as well.

Comment: You could mention CoolProp too: it is a C++ thermodynamics properties "library" which has binding for a plethora of languages/programs, including Excel and Matlab. You can think as an "Open Source Refprop".

Answer (score 1):

The thermal conductivity of seawater is 0.6 W/mK at 25 °C and a salinity of 35 g/kg. The thermal conductivity decreases with increasing salinity and increases with increasing temperature.

Comment: thanks for the info, what about the heat capacity?

Comment: You can find some additional info here :https://socratic.org/questions/how-does-salt-change-the-specific-heat-capacity-of-water